# xml imported in another xml -- how does this get into the war?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a Spring/Java application in a war file which fails with his error when run in Eclipse on Tomcat.

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:       Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:applicationContext-common.xml]
Offending resource: class path resource [spring/applicationContext-jem-web.xml]; nested exception is      org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException   parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext-common.xml];  nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext-common.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The file applicationContext-jem-web.xml indeed tries to import the missing file:

```
<import resource="classpath:applicationContext-common.xml"/>
```

This makes perfect sense in that the war file the applicationContext-jem-web.xml is found but not the applicationContexy-common.xml.

But this has worked in the past! We have to build with Maven Install from the command line and then in Eclipse we do things like Maven Update or we Maven Install again in Eclipse (sometimes for some reason removing Maven nature and then configing it again works). So my question is twofold: how does this ever work and what steps would be recommended to get this to run on Tomcat in Eclipse?

EDIT: This was a foolish question, missing environment variable variable.

Comment: You should post the structure of the project, at least the folders that contain these XML files. But if i had to guess then i would change your import to: `<import resource="classpath:spring/applicationContext-common.xml"/>`. Seems like the other XML file is under the spring/ directory, maybe this one is too?

Comment: The application is huge and the applicationContext-common.xml is in a separate project. I can't change the file. I am asking how it ever worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have posted this, due to failure to set env variables.